# Elasticsearch - Query by parent id

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three document types with the following mappings with Parent/Child relationships. I have omitted other properties as I thought they are not relevant to the question.

```
   "mappings": {
     "Parent": {            
        },
     "Child": {
        "_parent": {
           "type": "Parent"
        },
        "_routing": {
           "required": true
        }             
     },
     "GrandChild": {
        "_parent": {
           "type": "Child"
        },
        "_routing": {
           "required": true
        }             
     }
  }
```

I'm using java api to insert documents to the index. Before indexing a document, existing  documents with the same ids needs to removed to avoid duplicates. Parent's Id and Child's Id are stored externally. First all "GrandChild" documents are deleted using a term query on its parent id (which is an id of type "Child" in this case). There are no errors but the "GrandChild" docs are not getting deleted.

By running the following term query using the chrome plugin Sense, I found out that the problem is in the term query. It doesn't return hits. Parent, Child and GrandChild have the same routing value which is set to the id of Parent. This is the query I tried.

```
POST /myindex/GrandChild/_search?routing=DFC0E8CD59EBC00EC2DDC9A0FF5D1F2DB272B2449680824CCE60B6864568D498
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "_parent" : "//id/of/doc/of/type/Child" }
    }
}
```

When I try to search for a "Child" document using its parent id, it works. I get a "Child" using the following query.

```
POST /myindex/Child/_search?routing=DFC0E8CD59EBC00EC2DDC9A0FF5D1F2DB272B2449680824CCE60B6864568D498
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "_parent" : "DFC0E8CD59EBC00EC2DDC9A0FF5D1F2DB272B2449680824CCE60B6864568D498" }
    }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong in the "GrandChild" search?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer for the question from elasticsearch mailing list
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/d_aZejNMBD8

There is an open issue for this here:
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5399

**Edit :**
As shown in the Github issue the way to perform your query is to prefix the ID by the parent type :

```
POST /myindex/GrandChild/_search?routing=DFC0E8CD59EBC00EC2DDC9A0FF5D1F2DB272B2449680824CCE60B6864568D498    
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "_parent" : "Child#//id/of/doc/of/type/Child" }
    }
}
```

Comment: this not working in elasticsearch 5+
you need to use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-parent-id-query.html